# SQL IN query produces strange result

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Please see the table structure below:

```
CREATE TABLE Person (id int not null, PID INT NOT NULL, Name VARCHAR(50))
CREATE TABLE [Order] (OID INT NOT NULL, PID INT NOT NULL)

INSERT INTO Person VALUES (1,1,'Ian')
INSERT INTO Person VALUES (2,2,'Maria')
INSERT INTO [Order] values (1,1)
```

Why does the following query return two results:

```
select * from Person WHERE id IN (SELECT ID FROM [Order])
```

ID does not exist in Order. Why does the query above produce results? I would expect it to error because I'd does not exist in order.

Comment: `ID` *isn't* in `[order]` (You have `OID` & `PID`)

Comment: It doesn't return two results.

Comment: @AlexK, that is the point. I expect the query to error but it does not.

Comment: i don't think this is a bad question... yes, it's about a typo, but I would expect as well it to give an error... maybe the title of the question should be improved

Comment: You have no error because ID exists in Person. You can use a field of main table in your subquery field list.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem here is that you're not using `Table.Column` notation in your subquery, table `Order` doesn't have column `ID` and `ID` in subquery really means `Person.ID`, not `[Order].ID`. That's why I always insist on using aliases for tables in production code. Compare these two queries:

```
select * from Person WHERE id IN (SELECT ID FROM [Order]);

select * from Person as p WHERE p.id IN (SELECT o.ID FROM [Order] as o)
```

The first one will execute but will return incorrect results, and the second one will raise an error. It's because the outer query's columns may be referenced in a subquery, so in this case you can use `Person` columns inside the subquery.
Perhaps you wanted to use the query like this:

```
select * from Person WHERE pid IN (SELECT PID FROM [Order])
```

But you never know when the schema of the `[Order]` table changes, and if somebody drops the column `PID` from `[Order]` then your query will return all rows from the table `Person`. Therefore, use aliases:

```
select * from Person as P WHERE P.pid IN (SELECT O.PID FROM [Order] as O)
```

Just quick note - this is not SQL Server specific behaviour, it's standard SQL:

- [**SQL Server demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a18a4/1)
- [**PostgreSQL demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/a18a4/2)
- [**MySQL demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a18a4/2)
- [**Oracle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a18a4/15)

Comment: there's none, my answer is about it. May be I was not clear. My answer is about using aliases helps to avoid such a mistakes

Comment: Thanks+1. Is this a correlated sub query?

Comment: @w0051977 it's an interesting question. I think when it's used without alias, it's correlated, because it's using value from outer query, but when it's aliased, it's just stand-alone query, like cte. Here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery correlated subquery is defined like 'subquery that uses values from the outer query'

Comment: I can't see when a correlated su query would be useful. Could you provide an axample?

Comment: Actually I work with SQL Server, but never used term correlated subquery at work :) but, you can rewrite your example like `select * from Person as P WHERE exits (SELECT * FROM [Order] as O where O.PID = P.pid)` - now your subquery looks like correlated

Comment: Since you insist on the *"ALWAYS"* using aliases part, you should change the `select *` to `select p.*`

Comment: @ypercube don't think so, I can select data by * without aliases from many different tables. Main goal of aliases is to make joins and subqueries work predictable.

Comment: I thought that the main goal of aliases was to improve readability.

Comment: @swasheck improve readability and make queries predictable :) the rule is not to use `*` in production code also. When I specify columns explicitly, I use aliases before column names, `*` here is just to make example query shorter.

Comment: To be fair, you could also say `SELECT <cols> ...` to imply that `SELECT *` is bad.

Comment: @AaronBertrand close to truth :) Just wanted to point on specific problem here and show query that as close as possible to OP query. I'm sure there'll be a question about view with select * later :)

Comment: I could also rename OP tables to imply that using keywords as table name is bad

Comment: It's not about aliases, it's about specifying table name in front of column name: SELECT tablename.columnname FROM tablename

Comment: @Andrew yes and no, it's possible to do with table names, but I think aliases is more general way to do this (there could be self-joins, for example)

Comment: The specific problem was not because aliases weren't used, but because table name was not specified. If you want you can use alias as well, but the cause for problem doesn't change

Comment: @Andrew I've not said that the problem is because of not using aliases, I've said that I insist on using aliases to avoid that. The problem is clearly about not using table.column notation. May be I wasn't very clear about that in my answer

Answer (score 11):

This behavior, while unintuitive, is very well defined in Microsoft's Knowledge Base:

[KB #298674 : PRB: Subquery Resolves Names of Column to Outer Tables](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/298674)

From that article:

> To illustrate the behavior, use the following two table structures and query:

```
CREATE TABLE X1 (ColA INT, ColB INT)
CREATE TABLE X2 (ColC INT, ColD INT)
SELECT ColA FROM X1 WHERE ColA IN (Select ColB FROM X2)
```

> The query returns a result where the column ColB is considered from table X1.
>
> By qualifying the column name, the error message occurs as illustrated by the following query:

```
SELECT ColA FROM X1 WHERE ColA in (Select X2.ColB FROM X2)
```

> Server: Msg 207, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
>   
> Invalid column name 'ColB'.

Folks have been complaining about this issue for years, but Microsoft isn't going to fix it. It is, after all, complying with the standard, which essentially states:

> If you don't find column x in the current scope, traverse to the next outer scope, and so on, until you find a reference.

More information in the following Connect "bugs" along with multiple official confirmations that this behavior is by design and is not going to change (so you'll have to change yours - i.e. **always use aliases**):

[Connect #338468 : CTE Column Name resolution in Sub Query is not validated](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/338468/cte-column-name-resolution-in-sub-query-is-not-validated)

[Connect #735178 : T-SQL subquery not working in some cases when IN operator used](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/735178/t-sql-subquery-not-working-in-some-cases-when-in-operator-used)

[Connect #302281 : Non-existent column causes subquery to be ignored](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/302281/non-existent-column-causes-subquery-to-be-ignored-rather-than-errored-out)

[Connect #772612 : Alias error not being reported when within an IN operator](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/772612/alias-error-not-being-reported-when-within-an-in-operator)

[Connect #265772 : Bug using sub select](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/265772/bug-using-sub-select)

In your case, this "error" will probably be much less likely to occur if you use more meaningful names than ID, OID and PID. Does `Order.PID` point to `Person.id` or `Person.PID`? Design your tables so that people can figure out the relationships without having to ask you. A `PersonID` should always be a `PersonID`, no matter where in the schema it is; same with an `OrderID`. Saving a few characters of typing is not a good price to pay for a completely ambiguous schema.

You could write an `EXISTS` clause instead:

```
... FROM dbo.Person AS p WHERE EXISTS 
(
  SELECT 1 FROM dbo.[Order] AS o
  WHERE o.PID = p.id -- or is it PID? See why it pays to be explicit?
);
```

Comment: Yes man, that is really well defined answer supported with a many facts. I appreciate your effort.

Answer (score 0):

Order table doesnt have id column

Try these instead:

```
select * from Person WHERE id IN (SELECT OID FROM [Order])
```

OR

```
select * from Person WHERE pid IN (SELECT PID FROM [Order])
```