# Is IN and NOT IN mutually Exclusive?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables

**Table 1**

```
Column1
_______
   1
   2
   3
   4
   5
   6
```

**Table 2**

```
Column 1
________
    4
 NULL    //This NULL value added after answering the question, to show the real problem
    5
    6
    7
    8
    9
```

This is an example case. When I tried,

```
SELECT column1 FROM Table1 WHERE column1 IN (SELECT column1 FROM Table2)
```

I got 4,5,6

WHEN

```
SELECT column1 FROM Table1 WHERE column1 NOT IN (SELECT column1 FROM Table2)
```

**I didn't get 1,2,3 but NULL**.

In real case the column1 of table1 is nvarchar(max) and column1 of table2 is varchar(50). However, I tried casting both into varchar(50).

Comment: You haven't shown the `NULL` that's present in one row of `Table2`.

Comment: Works not as you've described as others have mentioned you must be having another problem: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a189e/4

Comment: Perhaps SSMS output is confusing you. It must say somewhere that 0 rows are returned.

Comment: @mootinator I updated the question with a NULL value in table 2. while asking the question I didn't know that this was the problem.

Comment: @ypercube I didn't get what were you mentioning. Sorry!

Comment: I meant that no rows are returned with the `NOT IN` query if there is at least one NULL at `table2.column1`. Do you use SSMS (Management Studio) or something else to run the queries?

Comment: @ypercube Ya I tried SSMS and Visual Studio to execute the query. Both executed the same.

Comment: OK. Then what did you mean with *"Sorry, its the NULL itself being returned."*?

Comment: @ypercube I told it was 0 returned first. But really Null was returned. That's why I said so.

Comment: How many rows of Nulls do you see returned? What you are saying, cannot happen really. You have zero rows returned.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check the documentation for [`IN`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177682.aspx), specifically:

> Any null values returned by *subquery* or *expression* that are compared to *test_expression* using IN or NOT IN return UNKNOWN. Using null values in together with IN or NOT IN can produce unexpected results.

You haven't *shown* them, but I'm *certain* that you've got at least one `NULL` value lurking in your data.

You can exclude the `NULL`(s) and then the `NOT IN` will work as you expected:

```
SELECT column1 FROM Table1
WHERE column1 NOT IN (SELECT t2.column1 FROM Table2 t2
                      WHERE t2.column1 IS NOT NULL)
```

---

`IN` and `NOT IN` are, within a hand wave, opposites, but you have to keep SQL's [three-valued logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic) in mind. Imagine we'd written the `IN` using the *expression* form

```
a IN (1,2,NULL)
```

Which is treated the same as:

```
a = 1 OR a = 2 or a = NULL
```

For any row where a = 1, we have:

```
TRUE OR TRUE OR UNKNOWN
```

which is `TRUE`. And for any row where a = 3, say, we have:

```
FALSE OR FALSE OR UNKNOWN
```

which is `UNKNOWN`

Now, consider `NOT IN` in the same way:

```
a NOT IN (1,2,NULL)
```

Which is treated the same as:

```
a != 1 AND a != 2 AND a != NULL
```

For any row where a = 1, we have:

```
FALSE AND TRUE AND UNKNOWN
```

Which is `FALSE`. And for a = 3, we have:

```
TRUE AND TRUE AND UNKNOWN
```

Which is `UNKNOWN`. The presence of the `NULL` means that there's no way to ever get this chain of `AND`s to produce a `TRUE` value.

Comment: Anything about 'mutually exclusive' to make this answer a little more better?

Comment: @SubinJacob - I wouldn't use that exact phrase but I've added more explanation which may help

Answer (score 6):

That may happend if you have `null` values in your Table2. Use this query instead:

```
select *
from Table1 as t1
where not exists (select * from Table2 as t2 where t2.column1 = t1.column1);
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e8210/5)</kbd>**

Test query:

```
-- Table2 doesn't have null values, works good
SELECT column1 FROM Table1 WHERE column1 IN (SELECT column1 FROM Table2);
SELECT column1 FROM Table1 WHERE column1 NOT IN (SELECT column1 FROM Table2);

insert into Table2
select null;

-- nothing returned by query, because of null values in Table2
SELECT column1 FROM Table1 WHERE column1 NOT IN (SELECT column1 FROM Table2);

-- works good
select *
from Table1 as t1
where not exists (select * from Table2 as t2 where t2.column1 = t1.column1);
```

This is happens because [three-valued logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic) of SQL, see Damien_The_Unbeliever [nice explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18865243/1744834). You can use `not null` query, like this:

```
SELECT column1 FROM Table1 WHERE column1 NOT IN (SELECT column1 FROM Table2 where column1 is not null);
```

But I like `exists` better, because it's filter out null implicitly (just because using `=`) condition.

As an addition, don't use query like ones in your question without aliases (actually not aliases, but dot notation, like `Table.column` or `Alias.column`), because you can have [incorrect results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18577622/sql-in-query-produces-strange-result/18579128#18579128). Always use dot notation for your columns. So your query should be something like:

```
SELECT t1.column1 FROM Table1 as t1 WHERE t1.column1 NOT IN (SELECT t2.column1 FROM Table2 as t2 where t2.column1 is not null);
```

Answer (score 3):

This is they main reason why you should avoid NOT IN, it's based on three-way logic, YES/NO/UNKNOWN :-)

```
col IN (1,2,NULL) 
is the logically equivalent to 
col=1 OR col=2 OR col=NULL 

col NOT IN (1,2,NULL) 
is the logically equivalent to
col<>1 AND col<>2 AND col<>NULL
```

Now any comparison to NULL evaluates to UNKNOWN, only "col IS (NOT) NULL" is correct.

If you got ORed conditions an UNKNOWN doesn't matter, but a single UNKNOWN in ANDed conditions results in a final UNKNOWN.

When you add a NULL to the outer table1 and remove the NULL from table2 you'll notice that this row is missing in both IN/NOT IN answer sets.

The best workaround is using EXISTS/NOT EXISTS instead, there's only YES/NO because conditins evaluating to UNKNOWN are kind of ignored and simply treated as FALSE.

Comment: I swear I was editing my question and hadn't seen yours when I added my explanation using the expression form. I guess `(1,2,NULL)` is the quintessential example for explaining it.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: no problemo, great minds think alike :-)  And your explanation is more detailed.