# select name and email and count using subquery in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying write a Postgres query to display a distinct number of people but count the actual (non-distinct) number of people.

So if I have

```
1  Ray ray@gmail.com
2  Ray ray@gmail.com
3  Kate kate@gmail.com
```

I'd want to show:

```
Ray 2
Kate 1
```

==

```
SELECT name, email, COUNT(*) 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT name, email 
FROM people
WHERE degree = 'Gradiate')
```

I get:

```
ERROR:  subquery in FROM must have an alias
LINE 3: FROM (SELECT DISTINCT name, email
```

How to fix this?

Comment: The error asks for alias add an alias simple

Comment: possible duplicate of [subquery in FROM must have an alias](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14767209/subquery-in-from-must-have-an-alias)

Answer (score 3):

You do not need the subquery at all (which would require a table alias as has been pointed out). It wouldn't make sense for what you need.

Use `GROUP BY` like this:

```
SELECT name, email, count(*) AS ct
FROM   people
WHERE  degree = 'Graduate'
GROUP  BY 1, 2;
```

`GROUP  BY 1, 2` is shorthand for `GROUP  BY name, email` in this case. [Example with more details.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20021602/find-movies-with-highest-number-of-awards-in-certain-year-code-duplication/20090089#20090089)

Of course, `name` *and* `email` have to match here, unlike your example where you only display `name` and count (which contradicts your query).

Comment: @Nona: `Ray ray_foo@gmail.com` and `Ray ray_bar@gmail.com` and `Ray NULL` (`NULL` value for email) will all be listed *separately* in the result (same name but different email).

Answer (score 0):

Add an

```
AS some_alias
```

Like:

```
SELECT name, email, COUNT(*) 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT name, email 
FROM people
WHERE degree = 'Gradiate') as my_alias
```

Comment: I get: ERROR:  column "my_aliasname" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 2: SELECT name, email, COUNT(*)

Comment: Sounds like a typo.  Can we see the exact query you're running after adding the alias?

Comment: It should read "my_alias.name" in my comment above.  Your query is what I'm running (assuming I understood you correctly)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name, count(*) AS count
FROM   people
WHERE  degree = 'Gradiate'
GROUP  BY name;
```